# How to handle org.netbeans.* under Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans, layout-manager

I'm trying to migrate from netbeans to eclipse and I have this line which I couldn't be able to know how to change it :

> org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout()

How do I to fix this line to make it work under Eclipse, please?

Comment: Are you using Maven, Gradle, Ivy, or the like?

Comment: Any GUI that uses `AbsoluteLayout` would be pretty poor IMO.  Try commenting it out and correcting the compilation errors with a combination of JSE layout managers.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, the only error that I'm getting is `org.netbeans cannot be resolved`

Comment: Then just comment it out (or completely remove that import) and proceed!

Comment: How do you plan to migrate any existing GUI editor `.form` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JAR containing `org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout()` may be found in the NetBeans distribution. On Mac OS X, for example, it's here:

```
NetBeans 7.4.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java/modules/ext/AbsoluteLayout.jar
```

```
$ jar tf NetBeans\ 7.4.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java/modules/ext/AbsoluteLayout.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
org/
org/netbeans/
org/netbeans/lib/
org/netbeans/lib/awtextra/
org/netbeans/lib/awtextra/AbsoluteConstraints.class
org/netbeans/lib/awtextra/AbsoluteLayout.class
```

As an aside, now may a good time to remove the dependency by using a suitable [layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).